# Bot Framework LuisDialog mixing Dialogs

Tags: c#, frameworks, artificial-intelligence, bots, azure-language-understanding

I am trying to build a luis ai bot using Microsoft bot framework. is it possible to get user in put with in an intent?

ex:

```
    internal static IDialog<Order> MakeRootDialog()
    {
        return Chain.From(() => FormDialog.FromForm(Order.BuildForm));
    }

    [LuisIntent("SWO")]
    public async Task StartWo(IDialogContext context, LuisResult result)
    {
        if (no == 0)
        {
            Message message = new Message();
            await Conversation.SendAsync(message, MakeRootDialog );
        }
        else
        {
            string message = "starting work ";
            await context.PostAsync(message);
            context.Wait(MessageReceived);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi if you required the user's whole question/query to the intent, then you will get in from the `LuisResult`class.

ex: `[LuisIntent("SWO")]
    public async Task StartWo(IDialogContext context, LuisResult result)
    {
     string userText =  result.Query;
    }`